# Optimize Java Code in fetching assistant id

Tags: java, list, java-8, jdbctemplate

Requirement : I have a file from which I need to add the assistant employee id corresponding to it's manager into db. So in file I am getting login id of assistant. I need to pass the login id to db in order to fetch the corresponding employee id of the assistant and add into the list which I am getting from file.

```
// code for getting employee from file - returns a list

private void setAssistantEmployeeId(List<E> empFile){
    List<E> empFilter = empFile.stream().filter(emp -> emp.getLoginId()!=null).collect(Collectors.toList());
    
    String sql = "SELECT ID FROM EMPLOYEE WHERE LOGIN_ID = ";
    
    List<E> tempList = new ArrayList<>(empFilter);
    
    for(E emp : empFilter){
        tempList.addAll(jdbcTemplate.query(sql+emp.getLoginId(), (resultset,i)->{
            emp.setAssistantEmployeeId(resultset.getString("ID"));
            return emp;
        }));
    }
}
```

The above code is working as expected but it's taking lot of time to execute. I need some help to optimize this code. Can someone please help me in optimizing this code?

Thank you.

Comment: What happens when I change my login ID to [`'Robert'); DROP TABLE employee; --`](https://xkcd.com/327/)?

Comment: You can fetch all IDs by all LOGIN_ID using In query and set ID

Answer (score 0):

```
private void setAssistantEmployeeId(List<E> empFile) throws SQLException {
    List<E> empFilter = empFile.stream().filter(emp -> emp.getLoginId()!=null).collect(Collectors.toList());

    //1. query all LOGIN_ID
    String sql = "SELECT ID, LOGIN_ID FROM EMPLOYEE WHERE LOGIN_ID IN (" + empFilter.stream().map(emp -> emp.getLoginId())
            .collect(Collectors.joining("','")) + ")";

    // create map[LOGIN_ID, ID]
    ResultSet rs = runQuery(sql); // execute this query in your way
    Map<String, String> id_loginId = new HashMap<>();
    while (rs.next()) {
        id_loginId.put(rs.getString("LOGIN_ID"), rs.getString("ID"));
    }

    // 3. assign ID value
    empFilter.forEach(e -> {
        e.setAssistantEmployeeId(id_loginId.getOrDefault(e.getLoginId(), ""));
    });
}
```

Comment: at step 3 e.getLoginId is coming null